# Can someone recommend me some Vishnu bhajans in Hindi, Sanskrit or Bengali?

Tags: vishnu

I would like to listen to some Vishnu bhajans in Hindi, Sanskrit or Bengali. Though I have searched on the web countless times for Vishnu bhajans, I have found only 3:

1. Shreeman Narayana Narayana Hari Hari
2. Jai Jagadish Hari
3. Shree Vishnu Amritwani

It would be very good if someone could provide me with more bhajans especially in Bengali (because I haven't found a single Vishnu bhajan in that language).

Comment: You can use chat for this. Users share many videos and bhajans in the chat rooms. I don't think this is a good question for the main site.

Comment: @sreeCharan Can you pleas share any link of that chat because I am also interested in getting stuffs like that :)

Comment: @Rishabh You can visit [Vedanta and philosophy]() and [Agama and Tantra]() rooms for such bhajans, keerthans. Users share some good bhajans there. You can see them in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com). Click this link adn you will see active rooms. :)

Comment: Here is one, it's Sri Nrisimha Pranama by Krishna Kshetra Das, a disciple by Srila Prabhupada: http://audio.iskcondesiretree.com/02_-_ISKCON_Swamis/ISKCON_Swamis_-_D_to_P/His_Holiness_Krishna_Kshetra_Swami/Bhajans/Krishna_Kshetra_Sw_Bhajans_-_Sri_Nrisimha_Pranama.mp3 --- (copy and paste the link manually in your web browser)

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I know the one you recommended but I was looking for Vishnu bhajans and not the bhajan of his 4th avatara

Comment: Lord Nrisimha is also Vishnu ;) ... http://audio.iskcondesiretree.com/index.php?q=f&f=%2F02_-_ISKCON_Swamis%2FISKCON_Swamis_-_D_to_P%2FHis_Holiness_Krishna_Kshetra_Swami%2FBhajans --- (copy and paste the link manually in your web browser)

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I know that and I have His bhajans. However, I am looking for bhajans of the original Vishnu.

Comment: Who is the original Vishnu?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Mahavishnu

Comment: I'm not aware of some bhajans particularly about Mahavishnu. Btw, Gaudiyas think that the original Vishnu is Lord Krishna. ;)

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Ik that. I am born and brought up in an area where such a belief is common. R u a Bengali?

Comment: No, I live in Europe, see my profile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some audio songs of Hari (Vishnu) in Hindi.

- [Teri beeti umar Hari nAm bina](http://198.15.68.162/35poD/music/bengali/movies/2013/t/the_light_swami_vivekananda/Dukh-Main-Sumiran-Sab-Kare-Sukh-Main-Kare-Na-Koi_(webmusic.in).mp3).
- [Peele re mann hari nAm ka pyAlA](http://198.15.68.162/35poD/music/bengali/movies/2013/t/the_light_swami_vivekananda/Pile-Pile-Re-Mann-Hari-Naam-Ka-Pyala_(webmusic.in).mp3).

Note: These songs are Hindi version of Bengali songs.

Comment: What is the name of the Bengali Version?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury These songs have been taken from this  movie. I am unable to find Bengali version for now. You can Google yourself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light:_Swami_Vivekananda

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Hindi [Bhajan of Satyanaryana](http://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/aarti/lord-narayan/shree-satyanarayan-aarti-hindi.html) which starts like this:

> जय लक्ष्मीरमणा श्री जय लक्ष्मीरमणा। सत्यनारायण स्वामी जनपातक हरणा॥ जय
>   लक्ष्मीरमणा।

And [here is another one](http://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/aarti/lord-narayan/shree-satyanarayan-aarti-hindi.html) called Purushottama Arati:

> श्री पुरुषोत्तम देव की आरती जय पुरुषोत्तम देवा, स्वामी जय पुरुषोत्तम
>   देवा। महिमा अमित तुम्हारी, सुर-मुनि करें सेवा॥

These Bhajans are sung during Artis, that is songs which are sung during waving lighted lamps.

Also, if you want Bhajans in Hindi for Narasimha, then the same site have them. Do a search.

Comment: You may also link audio or video version (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vK3ao6pUKLE)) so-that users can find how to sing or chant.